# JellyBean 4.2.2, SMSManager.sendTextMessage issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i have implemented sms/operator billing system in my app.
But facing permission issue on os 4.2.2 version. attached images shows the permission issue which was not present in earlier os version.

what are these permission?
how could i read thease permission
how to takle this?

any help would be appriciated!
[image: please notice dropdown option under send permission sms]

Comment: no need to change settings.. you can do it by code only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402043/issue-in-sending-sms-using-smsmanager-sendtextmanager-on-android/19853404#19853404

Comment: When you give your app some permissions in AndroidManifest.xml, your Android OS reads those permissions and warns about all those before installing the app.
Just click on Install.